# Compare two dates in Java, without compareTo

Tags: java, date, compareto

I'm writing my own `compareTo` method to compare two dates. How would I go about doing this?

I've thought about this question before, using tons of if statements, but there has to be a better way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `long` value?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to java.util.Date, just do `date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()`. A simple comparison of long values.

Answer (score 1):

There are three methods that might help [`Date.before(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)), [`Date.after(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) and [`Date.equals(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) you could do something like

```
public static int compareTo(Date a, Date b) {
  if (a.equals(b)) return 0;
  return (a.before(b) ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start:

```
public class MyComparator extends Comparator<Date> {
    public int compare(Date o1, Date o2){
        return o1.getTime() - o2.getTime();
    }
}
```

For example:

```
TreeSet<Date> ts = new TreeSet<Date>(new MyComparator());
ts.add(new Date(98796541));
ts.add(new Date(59586541));
System.out.println("Earlier is " + ts.first());
```